# How to execute jar file from Java code in Net Beans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a JAR file("AccessDB.jar" - on executing it, launches a tool). I have to access this jar file from this location (D:\NB\ProjFolder) in Netbeans 7.0. I tried reading it using ProcessBuilder, but it failed.

From this java code, I have to launch the tool (in jar file) by reading it. How can the code be modified for this?

```
public class classAccessDB {

public void GenerateAccessDB() {
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
try 
{
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_20\\bin\\java.exe", "-jar", "AccessDB.jar");
     pb.directory(new File("D:\\NB\\ProjFolder")); 
     Process p = pb.start(); 
     InputStream is = p.getInputStream(); 
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 

     String resultOutput = br.toString(); 
     System.out.println(resultOutput); 
}
catch(Exception E) 
{
     E.printStackTrace();
     System.out.println(E.getMessage());   
}
}
}
```

Comment: i face some problem while working on one of 3d design product which was expecting a executable jar file to run on specific action, What i did is Created a batch (windows) file which will have command to execute your jar file(if JRE is installed). And from the application execute the batch file. - I googled for "Creating EXE for Java Jar file" - Hope this will help you!!!! Try with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("batch file complete path");`

Comment: It might work if AccessDB.jar is an absolute path I think, instead of using pb.directory.

Answer (score 1):

Might be possible your **.jar** isn't executable. Instantiate classes or make call to any static method.

**Add Main-Class entry while creating a JAR.** into manifest file .

Then you can use

```
Process ps=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"java","-jar","yourJar.jar"});
        ps.waitFor();
        java.io.InputStream is=ps.getInputStream();
        byte b[]=new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(b,0,b.length);
        System.out.println(new String(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it worked for me when I did :

```
public class classAccessDB {

public void GenerateAccessDB() {
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
try 
{
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_20\\bin\\java\" -jar \"D:\\NB\\ProjFolder\\AccessDB.jar\"");

 Process p = pb.start(); 
 InputStream is = p.getInputStream(); 
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 

 String resultOutput = br.toString(); 
 System.out.println(resultOutput); 
}
catch(Exception E) 
{
  E.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println(E.getMessage());   
}
}
}
```

By the way your question helped me a lot thx :))

Comment: Your code will fail with: `C:\Program: No such file or directory`. If you paste all parts of the command into a single String, then spaces become a problem. Don't do that.

Comment: I edited my answer ... This way worked perfectly with me  ... try it and if it will work you can remove the -1 :P

Comment: The code now works but I still don't suggest to use the "put everything in one string" approach; it's always brittle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_20\\bin\\java.exe",
    "-jar",
    "D:\\NB\\ProjFolder\\AccessDB.jar");
```

instead. I saw in your code that you do change to the folder `D:\NB\ProjFolder` before starting the Java process and I would also think that should work. But using the absolute file name will work for sure.

If that doesn't work, look at the error message which you get; that should contain a clue what is wrong.